# Java Read Facebook Wall

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I'm building a web portal by using Java; besides other requirements, I'm struggling my mind one one very simple (at least at first view) requirement:
my customer wants on his portal the first N posts of his facebook wall
and he wants to read the first N tweets of his twitter page

Since my java code is based on Spring, I wanted to use spring social, spring social twitter and spring social facebook in order to satisfy the requirement

With twitter I had no problem; in fact I

- created an app on twitter
- got twitter app id and app secret
- prepared code

In a couple of hours, all worked pretty good

Problems were born with facebook and it's a lot of time I'm fighting with it
I passed from spring social to facebook4j (since this last one seems to me stronger).
I did the following

- created an app on FB
- got the facebook appId and appSecret
- told to the code that I need the read_stream permission
- prepared the code

But I'm not able in reading posts from my wall
Is there anyone who was able in satisfying this kind of scenario?
here my facebook4j code

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FacebookTest.class.getName());
public static void main (String[] a)
{
    try
    {
        ConfigurationBuilder cfgBui = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cfgBui.setDebugEnabled(true);
        cfgBui.setOAuthAppId(myAppId);
        cfgBui.setOAuthAppSecret(myAppSecret);
        cfgBui.setUseSSL(true);
        Configuration cfg = cfgBui.build();
        FacebookFactory ff = new FacebookFactory(cfg);
        OAuthSupport support = new OAuthAuthorization(cfg);
        support.setOAuthPermissions("read_stream");
        AccessToken appAccessToken = support.getOAuthAppAccessToken();
        Facebook face = ff.getInstance(appAccessToken );
        ResponseList<Post> posts = face.searchPosts("test");
        for (Post post : posts)
        {
            System.out.println(post.getId());
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Errore", e);
    }
}
```

As far as I understood, I should need the user access token, but I don't know how to generate it; should I create a login flow and show to the user the FB login dialog? If so, why should I create app id and app secret? They have no sense in my scenario
Moreover...in my case...the server side should authenticate on FB and read posts from a well know user wall (the wall of my customer...) so....where should I present the login dialog? where should I redirect after the FB login?

Is there any good man :) who can clarify to me the FB read post flow?

Answer (score 3):

You MUST use one of the possibilities to authorize the user (with read_stream) in order to get access to his stream. Here´s the link to all the possibilities: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

You can also generate Access Tokens with the Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Detailed information about Access Tokens and how to generate them can be found in the following links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Keep in mind that an Extended User Token only lasts for 60 days, after that your customer would have to refresh it manually. In general, you are not allowed to use User Profiles for commercial reasons, and it´s very unusual to show a User stream on a website.

Better: Use a Facebook Page. `/page-id/feed` with an Extended Page Token that lasts forever.

Comment: thank you for your answer; so in any case with facebook is not enough to get appId and appSecretId; we always (or when needed) should log and generate an user access token....I'm interested in the Facebook page idea but I don't know how it works...I'll try to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

If you use spring-social-facebook, you could let the user login via (front-end login flow) and then you can access the users wall. However, user would need to login and authorize your app to perform the operations.

Here is a spring social sample project that demo's how spring-social-facebook login is done https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples

Also, within your java code you can use feedoperations to gather information about home feed and also query against it. Checkout the documentation.

```
    facebook.feedOperations().
```

Comment: thank you Paul, I already saw the spring social samples and the feedOperations; sadly, as I said previously, what I don't like is the fact that i always should log in in order to get the user token. I'll try to use the PageOperations although i don't see any method to read page feeds

Comment: @AngeloImmediata page operations are for facebook pages..in your case you are looking for users posts to their wall right?

Comment: yest you are right; I need to show the last X posts on my customer site (I know it could be strange...but it's a requirement of my customer :) )

Comment: Hi...I'm still fighting with FB; I need to read my wall posts; how can I set the read_stream permission in Spring FacebookTemplate?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata when you generate your facebook app accesstoken from dev.facebook, you should select the read_stream premission.

Comment: if it worked, would be great if you accept my answer.. Thanks! Paul

Comment: I guess yuo should answer and not comment to my question in order i can accept it

Comment: sorry @AngeloImmediata i didnt follow that?

Comment: sorry @PaulJohn my mistake :)